# Receive multiple data via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to run some php code every (lets say) 2 seconds and update some text (in full code, there are data from MySql and many other). I decided to use ajax. I need to receive multiple data from Ajax. I tried to implement several responses for this problem here in stack overflow, but probably - i didnt do it right.

One of possible ways i tried to implement is this one:

html and js:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
        </head> 
  <body>
    <span id="jmeno1" style="font-weight:bold">aaa</span>:
    <span id="text1" style="font-weight:normal">bbb</span><br>

    <span id="jmeno2" style="font-weight:bold">ccc</span>:
    <span id="text2" style="font-weight:normal">ddd</span><br>

    <span id="jmeno3" style="font-weight:bold">eee</span>:
    <span id="text3" style="font-weight:normal">fff</span><br>
  </body>
    </html>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    setInterval(function() 
      {
      repeating();
      }, 2*1000);

    function repeating()
            {
            txt = "nic";
            $.post("repeating.php", {dd: txt}, function(data)
                {
                var result = $.parseJSON(data);
                $('#jmeno1').val(result.name);
                $('#text1').val(result.credit);
                });
                return false;
            };
    </script>
```

and this is php file:

```
<?php
$c_name="test1";
$c_credit="test2";

$data = array(
    'name' => $c_name,
    'credit' => $c_credit,
);
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Other way that i tried to implement and that also didnt work is below. 
HTML and js file is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    </head> 

<body>
  <span id="jmeno1" style="font-weight:bold">aaa</span>:
  <span id="text1" style="font-weight:normal">bbb</span><br>

  <span id="jmeno2" style="font-weight:bold">ccc</span>:
  <span id="text2" style="font-weight:normal">ddd</span><br>

  <span id="jmeno3" style="font-weight:bold">eee</span>:
  <span id="text3" style="font-weight:normal">fff</span><br>
</body>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript">

setInterval(function() 
  {
  repeating();
  }, 2*1000);

function repeating()
        {
        txt = "nic";
        $.post("repeating.php", {dd: txt}, function(value)
            {
            var data = value.split(",");
            $("#jmeno1").val(data[0]);
            });
            return false;
        };
</script>
```

And php file is:

```
<?php
$one = "test1";
$two = "test2";
echo $one.",".$two;
?>
```

Acctualy all i need is to receive array (or better arrays) via ajax. I would be grateful for help with this kind of solution or suggest any other. Thank you :).

Comment: Hi, does it receive any data on ajax call?

Comment: Hi. When i use one simple php variable and simple echo, it works. I think problem is in sending array.

Answer (score 0):

$.parseJSON is deprecated, use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
$.post("repeating.php", {dd: txt}, function(value) {
    var data = JSON.parse(value);
    $("#jmeno1").val(data[0]);
});
```

Comment: Thank your for your message, but it still doesnt work :/